# Bootstrap popover showing remote link content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap popover on some element. When mouseover on that element, a remote url content will be shown in the popup box.

I found this suggested solution, in case you want to use AJAX:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/8MtpL1vEUOU

But I thought there might be an easier way.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what does your remote url contain ?

Comment: @IamRaviteja it contains an ajax call to the server when it loads, and actually a visual graph generated by treant, jquery & bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<a href="/" class="btn btn-default btn-pop-over-element" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top">
  Popover on top
</a>

<script>

$('.btn-pop-over-element').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function () {
            $('.btn-pop-over-element').popover({content: '<p>This is a test content</p>', title: 'Test Title', html :true}).popover('show');    
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

You can also change the title and content according to response you recieve from ajax call. Also you can change the href url according to your need.